# Parse error: parse error, expecting PHP For Loop

Tags: php, parsing, for-loop

.

```
function is_valid_isbn($isbn)
{
  $isbn_length  =  strlen($isbn);
  $isbn_sum     = 0;
  echo "this is the length :";
  echo $isbn_length;
  for($i=0; $i < $isbn_length; $i++) { $total += (substr($isbn, $i, 1) * (11-($i+1))); }
 return true;
 }
```

When i run this function i am getting following error can some one help me where is the err ??

Here is the error message
Parse error: parse error, expecting `';'' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gbload\application\libraries\Isbnconv.php on line 47

Comment: I'm assuming the <br> tags are not in your actual code?

Comment: yeah there are no br tags in the code and
line 47 is for($i=0; $i < $isbn_length; $i++) { $total += (substr($isbn, $i, 1) * (11-($i+1)))

Comment: Should there be a `<` sign on line 47 between the `$i` and `$isbn_length` variables?

Comment: yeah there was < symbol in the condition statment of the for loop it got missed while i have copy pasted the code here.

Comment: Seems ok - http://codepad.org/wqD9B3Jw - also, btw, this always returns true

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: when programing using php, a void function should return true

Comment: @Bang - I thought the definition of a `void` function is that it doesn't return anything? - Also, why do you want to always return `true` (I'd understand returning some sort of error flag)?

Comment: @Bang - And by not returning anything I mean it returns `null`.

Comment: @Peter Ajtai: for easier to debug, all void function should return true <-- standard coding style

Answer (score 1):

Next time, pls tell us where is the line 47. See the fixed code below:

```
function is_valid_isbn($isbn)
{


  $isbn_length  =  strlen($isbn); //no br here
  $isbn_sum     = 0;//no br here
  echo "this is the length :"; //same 
  echo $isbn_length;//same
  for($i=0; $i < $isbn_length; $i++) //wrong here, missing the operator <
  { 
          $total += substr($isbn, $i, 1) * (11-$i+1); //too many ( )
  }//no br here
  return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while copy pasting..

my code was inded having the lessthan condition in the for loop
for($i=0; $i < $isbn_length; $i++) { $total += (substr($isbn, $i, 1) * (11-($i+1))); }

Comment: no the Error msg says there is some problem in the for loop line which is line numbe 47..

Comment: There're no parse error on my php-apache-local, then let try another way.So pls do the following things: 1. check your file encoding, is that utf-8 or something like that. 2. check if the current file is `Isbnconv.php` 3.copy 100% exactly that file's content to here. After that, we can try to find what is the cause again.

Answer (score 0):

```
for($i=0; $i$isbn_length; $i++)
```

maybe it should be: `for($i=0; $i==$isbn_length; $i++)` or something like that...

Comment: sorry that was my mistake while copy pasting the code it was having a lessthan symbol there
for($i=0; $i < $isbn_length; $i++) { $total += (substr($isbn, $i, 1) * (11-($i+1))); }